# Downloading a file from Adls gen1 using powershell is not working

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-lake

I am trying a download a file from azure data lake store using powershell script. The code is triggered from a runbook in azure cloud. Looks like `Export-AdlStoreItem` is not working as expected.I dont get any error messages or compilation errors. In fact when this command is executed a zero byte file is generated in the destination.The name of that file is `TemporaryFile2020-06-02_14-56-57.datc18371c2-d39c-4588-9af0-93aa3e136b01Segments`
what is happening?.Please help!.

```
$LocalDwldPath = "T:\ICE_PROD_DATA_SOURCING\FILE_DOWNLOAD_PATH\TemporaryFile$($TimeinSec).dat"
    $SourcePath = "Dataproviders/Landing/GCW/HPIndirect/Orders/AMS/gcw_hp_indirect_orders_ams_745_20200601_04_34_01.dat"
    $PRODAdlsName = "itgdls01"
    Export-AdlStoreItem  -Account $PRODAdlsName -Path  $("/" + $SourcePath.Trim()) -Destination $LocalDwldPath -Force -ErrorAction Stop
    if( Test-Path $LocalDwldPath.Trim() )
    {
    Get-Content -Path $LocalDwldPath.Trim() -ReadCount 1000 |% { $FileCount += $_.Count }   
        Remove-Item $LocalDwldPath.Trim()
        Set-Content -Path $cntCaptureFile -Value $FileCount
        $TimeinSec = TimeStamp2
        Add-Content -Value "$TimeinSec Log: Identified file for getting count is $($SourcePath.Trim()) and the count is $FileCount" -Path $logfile  
    }
    else
    {                       
        $TimeinSec = TimeStamp2     
        Add-Content -Value "$TimeinSec Error: Identified file for getting count is $($SourcePath.Trim()) and the count capture failed as local file is not found!" -Path $logfile
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the local download path/destination
(`"T:\ICE_PROD_DATA_SOURCING\FILE_DOWNLOAD_PATH\TemporaryFile$($TimeinSec).dat"`).
The T:\ drive is a virtual drive/network drive connected as Azure Fileshare.

Instead of T:\ , I have pointed the destination location to a local drive (`"F:\ICE_PROD_DATA_SOURCING\FILE_DOWNLOAD_PATH\TemporaryFile$($TimeinSec).dat"`) and it worked fine.

Its surprising that Powershell didn't give any error messages when it was not able to save the file in a network path pointed to azure fileshare.

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, if you want to download a file from azure data lake with PowerShell, we can use the PowerShell command [`Export-AzDataLakeStoreItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datalakestore/export-azdatalakestoreitem?view=azps-4.2.0).

For example

```
Export-AzDataLakeStoreItem -Account <> -Path '/test/test.csv' -Destination 'D:\myDirectory\test.csv'
```

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-powershell#rename-download-and-delete-data)